# TableView Covering up whole screen in View

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.1

I'm having trouble with the TableView I added into my ViewController. Problem is it is eating up the whole screen being black thus hiding everything else.
[image]
This is what I wanted but instead I got these
[image]
This is with constraints Horizontal Center and Top away from nearest neighbor
[image]

This is without any constraints. Table and cells are seen but it blocks up everything else.

Below is the code for my ViewController. I'd like to know how come the TableView is acting like that and how do I go about fixing it so that I get the result I want in the first picture.

```
class WalletViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var lblWalletAddress: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var tableViewAssets: UITableView!

var balance: [Balance] = []
var wallet = Wallet()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Wallet Details"

    self.tableViewAssets.delegate = self
    self.tableViewAssets.dataSource = self
}

public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return wallet.balance.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AssetTableCell")// as! AssetTableViewCell
    let assetTableCell = tableCell as! AssetTableViewCell

    assetTableCell.lblAssetName.text = wallet.balance[indexPath.row].asset
    assetTableCell.lblAssetAmount.text = String(wallet.balance[indexPath.row].amount)

    return assetTableCell
}
```

Comment: Can you please 1) crop your images and 2) remove unnecessary code?

Comment: @mLjH constraints are not properly applied thats why you face this type of  issue ,

Comment: @nivritgupta then how should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. Apparently it was because somehow default background color was black and I've to use Xcode's Suggested Constraints to make everything work together with the TableView. @nivritgupta was right. 
Thanks!